# Linux permissions issue from program

Tags: python, c, linux, shell, permissions

There is a convoluted way we do things where we have a C program which calls a shell script and which in turn calls a python script. This python script in turn tries to unzip a file using the unzip utility on the linux machine. Now, here is the problem. The unzip works absolutely fine when I execute the shellscript directly from the terminal (logged in as admin) which calls the python script which does the unzipping, where as the unzip is not allowed when the C program calls the shell script which calls the python script to unzip the file. So I tried to unzip directly from the C program and that fails too. I printed the current user using the whoami command in the C program and it says the user is admin which is the same user I log into the terminal as. Any ideas? Sorry for the long winded explanation. But I am at the end of a 12 hour day trying to figure this problem.

Comment: What does "unzip is not allowed" mean? Does it output an error? Does it return an error code? Does it explode? Is the environment the same when run from C? Is the C program running from cron or something? Is the C program running it in the same directory?

Comment: "C calling shell-script calling Python program" Sounds like an invitation to a security and maintenance nightmare. Why not using a single language?

Comment: How is the C program invoked? From the terminal command line? From cron? Is it setuid?

Comment: It returns an error code of 256 which maps permission being denied. The C program is one of the many processes that are started from a script when the system boots up. It keeps running continuously. No, we do not setuid. Cron is not involved.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you invoke the C program from some environment other than the command line. Perhaps you invoke it from cron or perhaps from a web server.

In any event, I also suppose that the current working directory of your process tree is a directory that doesn't allow admin to write there.

Add a call like one of these to ensure that your current working directory is useful to you.

```
chdir("/tmp")      # C
cd /tmp            # sh
os.chdir("/tmp")   # Python
```